# Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of:

Tags: jmeter

I need to pass variable(Extracted from response) from one Request to other Requests in the same Thread Group.

**Response of first Thread:**
42[
"createGameRsp",
{
"response": {
"title": "Create Successful",
"result": "Testo60 was successfully created. \n GameID: 56 \n Password: ",
"error": "",
"game": "texas",
"gameID": 56
}
}
]

**Another thread:**

42[
"get_joingame",
{
"uid": "Esdv7CHkwo1ATMfvY6NcWBTM5YB4d3nj",
"key": "AUEEW891WL",
"socketId":"${sid}",
"username":${userName}",
"avatar": "avatar17.jpg",
"language": "en",
"playerMove": "",
"joinGame": "",
"replay": 0,
"gameID":"${__property(GlobalGameID)}",
"gameNo": 0,
"data": "&seat=${counter2}&buyin=500&privateTable=2&clubId=0",
"players": 0,
"level": 347,
"lastAction": "ep.playNow",
"game": "texas",
"playMoney": 1,
"role": "1",
"playerId":"${playerId}",
"displayName": "p10",
"seat":"${counter2}"
}
]

I've used beanshell assertion to set variable in to jmeter property

${__set.Property(GlobalGameID,$(gameID))};

While executing i'm getting

Assertion error:true
Assertion failure:false
Assertion failure message:org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``${__set.Property(GlobalGameID,$(gameID))};'' : Attempt to access property on undefined variable or class name

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHV9O.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have an error in your function syntax

1. You need to remove the dot between `set` and `Property`
2. [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are referenced in form `${variable-name}`

   ```
   ${__setProperty(GlobalGameID,${gameID},)}
   ```

   Use [Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) to generate proper function syntax

Second, it's not recommended to inline JMeter Functions or Variables into Beanshell scripts, you can use `props` and `vars` shorthands instead:

```
    props.put("GlobalGameID", vars.get("gameID"));
```

Third, [it's not recommended to use Beanshell for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), if you need you should use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language as Groovy provides maximum performance comparing to other scripting engines

More information: [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)